# UICollectionView-make a specific cell to be wider?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using collection view to scroll vertically,we have 2 columns and each row has 2 cells.
We would like to make a specific cell to take the whole row place, so that this row will have one cell in it ,in the width of the screen .

problem is, when you do that, it works, but than you have to push all the other cells to the next position, so for cell 4 to take a full width:

```
0 1
2 3
4--
5 6
```

How can you push all cells forward/ do that effect in a more convenient way ?

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if(indexPath.item ==4)
        cell.frame=CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
```

I can change the data source,but it seems wrong,specially if you do that many times .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     if(indexPath.row==4)
     return CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 0.36*[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
    else
        return CGSizeMake(0.4*[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 0.36*[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);

}
```